# Distinguish subdoc operation errors from missing data on certain path

Tags: go, couchbase, gocb

I've got this code

```
frag, err := bucket.LookupIn(req.Key).Get(req.Path).Execute()
if err != nil {
    res.Code = 1
    res.What = err.Error()
} else {
    frag.Content(req.Path, &res.Data)
}
```

If I'm trying to request some path which does not exist in the document, I'm getting the error message `"could not execute one or more multi lookups or mutations"`, which also seems to occur on certain different circumstances. How can I distinguish missing data on path from all other kinds of subdoc errors? I'd like to have something like this:

```
frag, err := bucket.LookupIn(req.Key).Get(req.Path).Execute()
if err != nil {
    if <no data> {
        res.Code = 2
        res.What = "No data on specified path"
    } else {
        res.Code = 1
        res.What = err.Error()
    }
} else {
    frag.Content(req.Path, &res.Data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to compare the error values you get back against the list of known error types you can find here:
https://godoc.org/github.com/couchbase/gocb#pkg-variables

Comment: It seems there should be `ErrSubDocPathNotFound` error, but I'm getting `ErrSubDocBadMulti` instead, which does not make sence.